# Recursively render react component?

Tags: reactjs

If I have an object with 2 levels of hierarchy:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "Parent 1",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Child 1"
      },
      {
        name: "Child 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Parent 2",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Child 3"
      },
      {
        name: "Child 4"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Then I can render each item in React:

```
const Child = ({ children }) => {
  if (!children) return null;
  return (
    <ul>
      {children.map(item => {
        return <li key={item.name}>{item.name}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};

const Parent = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <li>{item.name}</li>
      <Child children={item.children} />
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(item => {
        return <Parent key={item.name} item={item} />;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

However if I didn't know how deep the nesting went, is there a way to recursively render a React component so all of the data will be rendered?

This demonstrates 3 levels of nesting but imagine there could be many more:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "Parent 1",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Child 1",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Sub-child 1"
          },
          {
            name: "Sub-child 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Child 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Parent 2",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Child 3"
      },
      {
        name: "Child 4"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is same as using a recursive function call. Use a function like:

```
const Children = (props) => <>
  <li>
    <p>{props.children.name}</p>
    {props.children.children && <ul>{renderChild(props.children.children)}</ul>}
  </li>
</>;

const renderChild = item =>
  item.map(it => (
    <Children children={it} />
  ));

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Nested Children</h1>
      <ul>{renderChild(data)}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, I kinda feel `children` is a reserved `prop` in React. Please check it out once.

**Preview**

[image]

**Working Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/vwqyq40zy