# Is it possible to dynamically generate linws checkbox tree?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, checkbox, tree

I have been playing around with my react project and I am trying to replicate my checkbox tree design. (I have linked the image).

I have a nice jsfiddle of a working solution, however, I am really struggling to see how I can use this in my project. Because I will need to dynamically generate my tree.

Is it possible to use this code to dynamically generate a tree and replicate my design?

I feel like the Pseudo styling will be tough to deal with if I map my data.

My data will look like this:

```
[
  {
    value: 1,
    data: "data",
    children: [],
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    data: "data2",
    children: [],
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    data: "data3",
    children: [
      {
        value: 1,
        data: "data",
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

code:

```css
.what {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
  
  ul.tree,
  ul.tree ul {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  ul.tree ul {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

  ul.tree li {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 0.60em;
    border-left: thin solid #000;
  }

  ul.tree li:last-child {
    border-left: none;
  }

  ul.tree li:before {
    width: 0.9em;
    height: 0.6em;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-bottom: thin solid #000;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
  }

  ul.tree li:last-child:before {
    border-left: thin solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="tree"><input class="what" type="checkbox" />Root</ul>
<ul class="tree">
  <li><input class="what" type="checkbox" /> Animals </li>
  <li><input class="what" type="checkbox" /> Animals
    <ul class="tree">
      <li><input class="what" type="checkbox" /> Animals </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="tree"><input class="what" type="checkbox" /> Root</ul>
<ul class="tree"><input class="what" type="checkbox" /> Root</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the HTML in your example is invalid. `input` elements cannot be direct children of `ul` elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursively render react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54040222/recursively-render-react-component)

Comment: Not necessarily, I have no issue rendering a react component recursively. The issue is rendering the react component recursively while also preserving the correct tree line styling that I have in my design.  Hopefully, that made sense @Sean

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying—that didn't come across in the question. Suggest posting the HTML that your recursive React component is generating as well as the CSS you've written so that we can see why it isn't working.